# Proguard giving the following error while exporting the application

Tags: android, proguard

```
Warning: library class android.webkit.WebView depends on program class android.webkit.WebViewClient   
Warning: there were 1 instances of library classes depending on program classes.   
       You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will   
        be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.   
 java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.   
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:308)   
at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:210)   
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:85)   
at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:499)
```

Can anyone specify the complete procedure to proguard my application.

Comment: Why this question has the down voting , it is the popular question , I have the badge for it.Any reviewer over here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17988163/1318946

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is described here:

[ProGuard manual > Troubleshooting > Warning: library class ... depends on program class ...](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dependency)

A complete configuration for Android is provided here:

[ProGuard manual > Examples > A complete Android application](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication)

However, the easiest way is probably the build process of the Android SDK, which includes ProGuard:

[Android SDK Dev Guide > Tools > ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html)