# Error while Setting of Proguard and Exporting APK

Tags: android, proguard

I am doing first-time Proguard setting on My Android Project and Exporting My APK File but I got Following errors:
(I also not found any `proguard.cfg` file in my project root)

```
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Note: there were 2 duplicate class definitions.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue: can't find referenced field 'int UNSET_EXPECTED_SIZE' in class com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue$Builder
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.google.common.primitives.UnsignedBytes$LexicographicalComparatorHolder$UnsafeComparator$1: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.salesman.activities.PlacesMapActivity: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.salesman.activities.PlacesMapActivity: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.MapController
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: com.salesman.activities.PlacesMapActivity: can't find referenced class com.google.android.maps.OverlayItem
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]       You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: there were 9 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]          You may need to specify additional library jars (using '-libraryjars').
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] Warning: there were 1 unresolved references to program class members.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]          Your input classes appear to be inconsistent.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]          You may need to recompile them and try again.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]          Alternatively, you may have to specify the option 
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]          '-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers'.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]     at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:321)
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]     at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:211)
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]     at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:86)
[2013-08-01 10:54:42 - SalesmanTracker]     at proguard.ProGuard.main(ProGuard.java:492)
```

**project.properties : **

```
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
proguard.config=proguard.cfg

# Project target.
target=android-17
android.library.reference.1=..\\librarySlideMenu
android.library.reference.2=../google-play-services_lib
```

Please tell me about the solution to that and how to do exactly the setting of proguard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I Got Answer with the help of this [Tutorial](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#)

I have changed following things:

In **project.properties:**
Uncomment or add this line:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Now I have used Google Library so my **`proguard.project.txt`** will be like:

Here add your libraries which you have used in your project:

```
-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar
-libraryjars /libs/gson-2.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/guava-11.0.1.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar
-libraryjars /libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
-libraryjars /libs/protobuf-java-2.2.0.jar
-libraryjars /libs/maps.jar
```

#### Add any project specific keep options here:

```
-keep class com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.**
```

Then you can Export your APK using following steps:

- Right click on project
- select Export
- Follow Steps

If you have any Query then you are free to ping me :)

Thank you.

Comment: it gives me IOException: The same input jar [.\libs\jsr305-3.0.1.jar] is specified twice.

Answer (score 3):

Using Maven in my case, `google-api-client` brought `guava-jdk5` as a dependency, causing similar problems.

Guava wiki page on Proguard suggests:
https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava

```
-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe
-dontwarn com.google.common.collect.MinMaxPriorityQueue
```

Comment: I found adding the following to progaurd-rules.pro when using guava worked for me: `-dontwarn sun.misc.Unsafe  
-dontwarn com.google.common.**`

Comment: You've practically excuded more classes from com.google.common package and below that's all, the end result should be pretty much the same since all except MinMaxPriorityQueue don't produce a warning anway so...

Answer (score 2):

Add these line in your proguard-project.txt

```
-keep public class com.google.common.**
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
```